# flutter: parar a atualização continua da váriavel auth provinda de um provider do firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, android-webview, android-content-provider

Quando chamo o webview com está variavel auth.usuario?.uid, a página web fica atualizando a cada 3 cliques nela, o que não ocorre quando eu não utilizo essa variável, mas, preciso indicar o id do usuário para essa página.

```
import 'package:heal_anality/home/custom_drawer.dart';
import 'package:heal_anality/widgets/buttons_menu.dart';
import 'package:heal_anality/widgets/custom_appbar.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

import '../services/auth_service.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  /* WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
      onPageStarted: (String url) {
        print('começou');
      },
    ))
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://unname.streamlit.app/?user=1')); */
  late AuthService auth;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    auth = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const CustomDrawer(),
      appBar: customappbar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const ButtonsMenu(),
          Expanded(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                double remainingHeight =
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - constraints.maxHeight;
                return SizedBox(
                  height: remainingHeight,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: WebViewWidget(
                      controller: WebViewController()
                        ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
                        ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
                          onPageStarted: (String url) {
                            print('começou');
                          },
                        ))
                        ..loadRequest(
                            Uri.parse('https://unname.streamlit.app/?user=${auth.usuario?.uid}'))),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Arquivo AuthService.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthExeption implements Exception {
  String message;
  AuthExeption(this.message);
}

class AuthService extends ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User? usuario;
  bool islogin = true;
  bool isLoading = true;

  AuthService() {
    _authCheck();
  }

  _authCheck() {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      usuario = (user == null) ? null : user;
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  _getUser() {
    usuario = _auth.currentUser;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  registrar(String email, String senha) async {
    try {
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: senha);
      _getUser();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        throw AuthExeption('A senha é muito fraca!');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        throw AuthExeption('Este email já está cadastrado');
      }
    }
  }

  login(String email, String senha) async {
    try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: senha);
      _getUser();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        throw AuthExeption('Email não encontrado. Cadastre-se.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        throw AuthExeption('Senha incorreta. Tente novamente');
      }
    }
  }

  logout() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
    _getUser();
  }
}
```

Tentei chamar o provider dentro do método build mas não tive sucesso, o erro continou.
Estou utilizando o firebase authentication para validar os usuários.